# Getting WHERE clause after Update statement

Tags: java, mysql

I am required to fetch the where clause after an update statement e.g.

```sql
UPDATE user_accounts SET bio='This is my bio' WHERE user_id = 1 OR name = 'Alex';
```

At the moment, I am able to get everything after the where clause with the following code:

```java
String query = "UPDATE user_accounts SET bio='This is my bio' WHERE user_id = 1 OR name = 'Alex'";
int index = query.toUpperCase().indexOf("WHERE");
if (index != -1) {
     System.out.println(query.substring(index));
}
```

But then I discovered that this was significantly flawed, since these sample queries would fail:

```sql
UPDATE user_accounts SET bio='This is where my bio is' WHERE user_id = 1 OR name = 'Alex';
UPDATE user_accounts SET whereColumn='' WHERE user_id = 1 OR name = 'Alex'
UPDATE user_whereabouts SET columnName='' WHERE user_id = 1 OR name = 'Alex'
```

Essentially, this fails if table name or any column name or column value under SET contains the word 'where' (case insensitive).

My thinking has currently been along the lines of a regex that does the following:

1. Checks if the word where is in between ' ' or " " (e.g. bio = "This is where my bio is") and skips it to move to the one which isn't inside the quotes. This will help eliminate the *where* words found in the SET values. Of course the Java quotes surrounding a string do not apply since they aren't part of the string itself.
2. Checks that the word where is sandwiched between spaces (e.g. ... WHERE ...). This will help eliminate the *where* words found in either table name or column name (SQL syntax itself can't allow table name or column name to solely be a reserved word).
3. Finally, returns the index of the wanted WHERE in order to get the substring (The objective of the question).

I am not very conversant with regexes and thus, I am in need of assistance. Please note that any other ways of achieving the objective will be highly appreciated as well.

Comment: You need to break up the query in tokens, where a string literal is a single token. Then the `WHERE` of the WHERE-clause will be a token, while the `where` inside a string literal isn't (because it is part of a larger token).

Comment: regular expression "\s+WHERE\s+" to ensure that "where" is the entire word but Mark's comment is more appropriate.

Comment: Things like this require tokenization.

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of SQL parser because regexes will fail short in many cases (for instance what if the where clause has a sub-select?)

I've never tried it but [JSQLParser](https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser/wiki/Examples-of-SQL-parsing) seems like a good solution

Answer (score 0):

Using **JSqlParser** this would look like:

```
List<String> sqls = Arrays.asList("UPDATE user_accounts SET bio='This is my bio' WHERE user_id = 1 OR name = 'Alex';",
    "UPDATE user_accounts SET whereColumn='' WHERE user_id = 1 OR name = 'Alex'",
    "UPDATE user_whereabouts SET columnName='' WHERE user_id = 1 OR name = 'Alex'");

for (String sql : sqls) {
    Statement stmt = CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);
    Update update = (Update)stmt;

    System.out.println("sql=" + stmt.toString());
    System.out.println("   where=" + update.getWhere());   
}
```

However you could improve your **where** search by using regular expressions, e.g. for with word boudaries:

```
\bwhere\b
```

but again you are right, this version is flawed as well for e.g. `set col = ' test where test'`.

The right way to do it, is to parse the whole sql via a parser (https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser).